# flutter code require ctrl+s to update the screen, setState() is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using provier in my app drawer to navigate to drawer menu screens... when i click on any item in drawer it does nothing but when i press ctrl+s it. takes me to the screen where i was supposed to go... where should i call setstate to automatically go to the desired screen without pressing ctrl+s

Here is my Drawer Code

```
class _DrawerClassState extends State<DrawerClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            drawerTop("HI USER"),
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                drawerItems(context, "HOME", NavigationItem.home),
                drawerItems(
                    context, "NOTIFICATIONS", NavigationItem.notifications),
                drawerItems(context, "PARTNERS", NavigationItem.partner),
                drawerItems(context, "LOCATIONS", NavigationItem.location),
                drawerItems(context, "FEEDBACK", NavigationItem.feedback),
                drawerItems(context, "CONTACT US", NavigationItem.contactus),
                drawerItems(context, "AWARDS", NavigationItem.awards),
              ],
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Image.asset("assets/images/page6_boxes.png",
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/facebook.png",
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/insta_icon.png",
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  drawerItems(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    NavigationItem item,
  ) {
    final provider = Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context);
    final currentItem = provider.navigationItem;
    final isSelected = item == currentItem;
    final color =
        isSelected ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 164, 1) : Colors.white;
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 0.0, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              selectItem(context, item);
             
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: color,
                    fontFamily: "Raleway Reg",
                    fontSize: 23,
                    letterSpacing: 2),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: const Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 3,
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}

void selectItem(BuildContext context, NavigationItem item) {
  final provider = Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context, listen: false);
  provider.setNavigationItem(item);
}
```

Here is the code where i am switching screens

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => buildPages();

  buildPages() {
    final provider = Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final navigationItem = provider.navigationItem;
    switch (navigationItem) {
      case NavigationItem.home:
        return HomeScreen();

      case NavigationItem.notifications:
        return Notifications();
      case NavigationItem.partner:
        return Partners();
      case NavigationItem.location:
        return Locations();
      case NavigationItem.feedback:
        return FeedbackScreen();
      case NavigationItem.contactus:
        return const ContactUs();
      case NavigationItem.awards:
        return Awards();
    }
  }
}
```

here is provider class

```
class NavigationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  NavigationItem _navigationItem = NavigationItem.home;

  NavigationItem get navigationItem => _navigationItem;

  void setNavigationItem(NavigationItem navigationItem) {
    _navigationItem = navigationItem;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: when you use provider, you need to wrap Consumer Widget to listen changes from provider class. https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html

Comment: it was working yesterday with the same code when i closed my laptop... i don't know what happened to it today.